# Self-energy in two scalar Yukawa interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, interactions, self-energy

> Considering the Lagrangian of two scalar fields in $d=4$:
>   $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial\chi)^2-\frac{1}{2}M^2\chi^2-g\phi^2\chi$$

What would be the self-energy (diagrams, first order) for the $\chi$-particle?
The second particle confuses me somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\chi$ particle seems to be interacting with the $\phi$ particle only in the $-g\phi^2\chi$ term, so the 1-loop correction to the $\chi$ propagator would be a loop of 2 $\phi$ particles. The first 4 terms are the kinetic and mass terms of the particles, while the rest (in this case 1) are the interaction terms - they tell you what type of particles (and how many of each) can appear in any given vertex (only 1 in this case), as well as the coupling constant ( in this case, the coupling constant is $g$ and has dimension of mass$^1$).